# Webpack - what are the differences between a production and development CSS's bundle

Tags: css, webpack

when you compile with webpack, what are the differences between a production and development's type CSS?

I have remarked it seems the prod stylesheet takes into account the whole website, however the dev mode seems to take into account only the page concerned by the development.

Hence some inconsistencies can occur when going on prod'mode, maybe there is other differences that are good to know?

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

On their own, the differences are as follows (all from their documentation), so it's probably more to do with the specific configuration that has been enabled on the codebase in question (namely, which plugins, loaders, devtools, etc are implemented in each environment):

`webpack --mode=development`

Sets `process.env.NODE_ENV` on `DefinePlugin` to value `development`. Enables `NamedChunksPlugin` and `NamedModulesPlugin`.

`webpack --mode=production`

Sets `process.env.NODE_ENV` on `DefinePlugin` to value `production`. Enables `FlagDependencyUsagePlugin` , `FlagIncludedChunksPlugin` , `ModuleConcatenationPlugin` , `NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin` , `OccurrenceOrderPlugin` , `SideEffectsFlagPlugin` and `TerserPlugin` .